# linear regression: Would these variables be considered multicollinear?

Tags: r, regression, linearmodels, multicollinearity

My linear model would be `Score ~ Age + Collection1 + Collection3`

I transform the `Collection` Column into dummy variables and I don't have `Collection5` column to prevent the dummy variable trap.

For Collection 1, 3, and 5, I am sampling the same people and the Collection period takes place at the same time (Collection 1 = year 2000, Collection 3 = year 2002, Collection 5 = year 2004) hence the +2 in age for the same contacts.

Would the variables `Age`, `Collection1`, and `Collection3` be multicollinear? On one hand, I feel like the increase in age is correlated with a higher collection but since Collection is transformed into multiple dummy variables of 1s and 0s, it shouldn't matter.

Is there a logical explanation as to why it should or shouldn't be multicollinear or break other assumptions?

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy38o.png)

Comment: Can you please post your example data in text format rather than as an image?

Comment: This sounds like a statistics question and not a coding question, and thus might be better for https://math.stackexchange.com/. However, the typical way of checking for multicollinearity is to run the VIF test. You can do that in R with for example `car::vif()`, se more [here](https://www.statology.org/multicollinearity-regression/).